# Javascript Help

Tags: javascript

I have a Array of objects. I need to filter the recently added Object Id in a Array

Example :

```
Array A : [{"Id":"001","Qty":"3","level":"2"},{"Id":"002","Qty":"3"},{"Id":"001","level":""},{"Id":"001","Qty":"4"},{"Id":"002","level":"2"}]

Output:
[{"Id":"001","Qty":"4"},
{"Id":"002","level":"2"]
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `Map` to accomplish this algorithm.

First, let's assume your `input` has been defined:

```js
let input = [
  {"Id":"001","Qty":"3","level":"2"},
  {"Id":"002","Qty":"3"},
  {"Id":"001","level":""},
  {"Id":"001","Qty":"4"},
  {"Id":"002","level":"2"}
];
```

---

From here, we simply add the values to the map, then grab the values back out:

```js
let output = new Map(
  input.map(
    (item) => [item.Id, item]
  )
).values();
```

First, the `input.map` creates a multidimensional array, such that you end up with:

```json
[
  ["001", {"Id":"001","Qty":"3","level":"2"}],
  ["002", {"Id":"002","Qty":"3"}],
  ["001", {"Id":"001","level":""}],
  ["001", {"Id":"001","Qty":"4"}],
  ["002", {"Id":"002","level":"2"}]
]
```

Which the Map constructor (`new Map(...)`) then uses to add the elements to the map. The first parameter is the key, which is unique within the Map; by reusing a key, the old item is evicted to hold the new item.

Finally, `.values()` gets the values as an Array from the Map.

Other techniques are also possible, such as using an `Object`, which behaves much like a `Map`:

```js
let output = Object.values(
  Object.fromEntries(
    input.map(
      (item) => [item.Id, item]
    )
  )
);
```

But this technique is a little more verbose, since you have to call `Object` functions.